Audit Logs for Outlook Calendar
I am working on analyzing Outlook calendars and need to determine if there are specific audit logs available for certain user actions.
I am looking for audit logs for the following specific actions in Outlook Calendar:

Action 1: When a user creates a new calendar (other than the primary calendar).
Action 2: When a user shares a calendar with others (including the role with which they share it).
Action 3: When a user deletes a created calendar (other than the primary calendar).

I have seen that Microsoft provides permission-related cases in the ExchangeItem record type.
Does Microsoft provide audit logs for these specific actions in Outlook Calendar? Additionally, is there any record type or activity available for auditing these actions?
Thank you in advance for your help!
